# GPO or Registry Entry for Old Control Panel Functionality

Tags: windows-11, control-panel

Right now if I opened Control Panel and clicked on Devices and Printers it would open up the Settings app's version, and if I right clicked on Control Panel's Devices and Printers instead and clicked Open it'd take me to the actual Control Panel page I was looking for.

Is there a GPO or a registry value somewhere I can set that'd make it so just clicking on a Control Panel setting will take me to the actual Control Panel setting page instead of redirecting to the Settings app?

Thank you.

---

edit: here's an example where I want to get to the "Services" tab of a bluetooth speaker's properties window.

Version 1: Control Panel > Right click Devices and Printers and choose Open > Open the speaker > Go to Services tab.

Version 2: Control Panel > Regular click on Devices and Printers > *Redirect to Settings app* > click into Devices > click More devices and printer settings > *back in Control Panel's version of Devices and Printers* open the speaker > Go to Services tab.

To be clearer - Control Panel isn't broken, it is behaving in an undesirable way and I'm just asking if there's a way to cut out the Settings app redirect through a GPO or registry entry.

Comment: @John uh that doesn't address the question in any way; Control Panel isn't broken it's just behaving in an undesirable way hence the question about a GPO or registry value. For simple unrelated maintenance reasons I've already run dism and sfc recently.

Comment: @John can you not respond if you're not going to read? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Possible work-around: One can make shortcut links to open the traditional CP dialog. For example, copy the following and paste into a new shortcut to get the *Sound* CPL:

```
C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe Shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL Mmsys.cpl,,0
```

Here are a few  more:

- Main CPL: `C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL`
- Mouse: `C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe Shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL main.cpl @0,0`
- Network Connections: `C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL ncpa.cpl`
- Regional Settings: `C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe Shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL Intl.cpl,,0`
- Remove Hardware: `C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe Shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL HotPlug.dll`
- Security: `C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL wscui.cpl`
- System Configuration: `C:\Windows\System32\msconfig.exe`
- System CPL: `C:\Windows\explorer.exe shell:::{BB06C0E4-D293-4f75-8A90-CB05B6477EEE}`

One can also make shortcuts to the new CPL using ms-settings. See the lists at [Winaero](https://winaero.com/ms-settings-commands-in-windows-10/) , at [[4sysops]](https://4sysops.com/wiki/list-of-ms-settings-uri-commands-to-open-specific-settings-in-windows-10/), and at [Pureinfotech](https://pureinfotech.com/windows-11-mssettings-uri-commands/). Note that Microsoft may change these with updates. Two examples:

- Personalization: `ms-settings:personalization`
- Windows Update: `ms-settings:windowsupdate`

Of course, one can set *keyboard* shortcuts to any of those links, to open the correct CPL item with a key combo.

Comment: Lol I see we were both having similar ideas! We posted our answers at about the same time.

Answer (score 1):

After combing through the GPOs and reading around a lot online about this, I see there likely isn't a switch *anywhere* that prevents this behavior as it's part of Microsoft's long effort to bring Control Panel settings into the Settings app. Some of them are half-migrated, resulting in an awkward UX where some can be changed in Settings and you're otherwise redirected back to CP for the rest.

If there are certain Control Panel pages you use most often and you want those to open immediately and on demand, you can create a shortcut to it using "`explorer shell::::{GUID}`" where GUID can be found from the "[Canonical Names of Control Panel Items](https://web.archive.org/web/20230209141449/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/controlpanel-canonical-names)" page.

In my case, I'd set the shortcut to point to "`explorer shell::::{A8A91A66-3A7D-4424-8D24-04E180695C7A}`" and any time I opened that shortcut it'd open directly on the *Devices and Printers* page.

Now, you can pick out your most frequent settings and create a folder for their respective shortcuts and that'd be convenient for future use - but that doesn't help if you need to work on someone else's computer. Truly the best use of your time would be just right clicking the Control Panel item and choosing Open from the context menu. :/

Comment: +1 for link to Canonical Names! Now I can make more shortcuts. Thanks.